# Auto-populate certain rows in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Not sure if excel has the power to do what I'm asking but I would like to create a worksheet and then from that worksheet choose specific rows to populate another work sheet simply by clicking on the row I want.

So for example i have information on rows 2-30 on worksheet A, but on worksheet B I only want rows 2,3,15 and 30.

Is there a way I can use 1 cell in worksheet A to populate worksheet B?

I know this is asking a lot from excel but if I can get it to work it would save me a lot of time and more importantly cut down a lot on the risk of making a mistake.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question well, but most probably you'll need to use macros for that. As this site isn't a free code writing service unfortunately we can't really help you with that. If you invest your time learning VBA then we are happy to help you when you stuck.

Comment: As @MátéJuhász already mentioned, you need to use a VBA macro like this one http://www.teachexcel.com/excel-help/excel-how-to.php?i=153830

Comment: I suspect you could use pre-populated place-holder formulas on the target sheet to display rows from the source sheet based on parsing a list of desired rows.  This would require solving a number of separate problems, such as the parsing formula, the lookups, display/format issues, knowledge of the worksheet structure, etc.  Each of those specific issues would be an appropriate scope for a question.  Asking for a canned solution to the entire thing is beyond the intended scope.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options. One option is to write a macro to achieve what you need. Another option is to use Excel's PivotTable functionality.
In Worksheet A, define your list. For example:

```
Item     | Enabled
------------------
Apple    |  1
Google   |  0
Subaru   |  1
Volvo    |  1
```

Select any cell in the above table, then go to **Insert** ribbon and click on **Table** button. This will define a 'table' object named `Table1` that can be easily referenced.

In Worksheet B, select an empty cell, then go to **Insert** ribbon and click on **PivotTable**. Specify `Table1` as the data source. In the PivotTable Fields pane (which will appear on the right hand side when any cell in the PivotTable is selected), drag **Item** column into **Rows** section and drag **Enabled** column into **Filters** section. In the PivotTable, click on the down-arrow next to Enabled cell and select `1` as the filter value. The PivotTable will now only show rows that are enabled.

You can make Pivot Table look a little slimmer by removing total rows: goto **PivotTable Tools \ Design** ribbon and click on **Grand Totals** button. Select **Off for rows and columns**.

Now, whenever you want to update your list, you just need to change the values in the Enabled columns to `1` or `0` (or any other value), then right-click the PivotTable and select **Refresh**.

Here's a screenshot of what the result may look like.
[image]